# ManytoManyField not returning str object

Tags: python, django

I have the 2 below models.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    Customer = models.OneToOneField(User)
    CustomerID = models.CharField(max_length = 15)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.Customer.username


class Customer_Coupons(models.Model):

    Customer_Det = models.ManyToManyField(Customer)
    Campaign_Det = models.ManyToManyField(Campaigns)
    Redeemed = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def Get_Customer_ID(self):
        return '\n'.join([p.CustomerID for p in self.Customer_Det.all()])

    def Get_Campaign_ID(self):
        return '\n'.join([p.CampaignID for p in self.Campaign_Det.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Customer_Det.CustomerID
```

I'm having a problem with the **str** method for Customer_wallet. I seem to be getting the below error when querying. Is there a better way to define the **str** method? I would preferably want a CustomerID or the Customer name which is again stored in a User table.

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type ManyRelatedManager)
```

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: are you allowing your customers to create multiple wallets? I think you must reconsider your database design !

Comment: yea .. the name of the function is a typo (it should refer to coupons) .. the customer is allowed to save many coupons In his 1 wallet .. I'm trying to recreate groupon using purely django. so this manytomany table will have customers and their related coupons

Comment: You seem to have totally the wrong model structure here. Why are you using many-to-many fields at all? A wallet cannot belong to multiple customers, surely? And specifically to your question, why do you want to return IDs in the `__str__` method? You should be returning a readable string.

Comment: Its not a wallet .. edited the typo.. basically each customer has a 1 wallet in which he can save many coupons.

Comment: Users can have many coupons and each coupon can belong to many users. At least that's the meaning of the ManyToManyField. If you want your coupon to belong only to one user, try a ForeignKey. It will also allow you to traverse `self.Customer_Det` the way you seems to expect it.

Comment: Yes .. thats the reason why i'm using the many to many field. Users can have many coupons(campaigns in this case) and each coupon can be used by multiple users. 

i'm sorry if i caused a lot of confusion. Should have a more strict naming convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Customer_Coupons.Customer_Det` field is a `ManyToManyField`, thus `self.Customer_Det` does not denote a single value.

You may want to iterate over all possible `Customer.CustomerID` in `self.Customer_Det` to build the return string. Or just use the first one you encounter, or whatever suits your needs.

Try:

```
return ' / '.join(cust.CustomerID for cust in self.Customer_Det.all())
```

Change `all` for `filter` or `get` depending on your needs.

---

### Edit

It appears, from the comments, that you expect your `Customer_Coupons` model to have each instances related to 1 customer and 1 campaign at a time. In this case, use a `ForeingKey` field for both of them instead of a `ManyToManyField`.
You will be able to access the related object fields the same way you are trying to in your question (i.e. `self.Customer_Det.CustomerID`).

If you need to have your coupons following both:

- Users can have several coupons;
- Coupons can belong to several users.

then do not expect instances of `Customer_Coupons` to relate to only 1 customer. Same goes for campaigns.

Comment: Actually , that's the reason why i tried self.Customer_Det.CustomerID hoping it will just return a value of the CustomerId of that particular instance. So it should go like **return [i.customerID for i in self.Customer_Det]** when you mean iterate?

Comment: Edited my answer for an example of an "iteration"

Comment: You stated in the comments of your questions that "Users can have many coupons(campaigns in this case) and each coupon can be used by multiple users." but here you expect to get "a value of *the* CustomerId of that particular instance". It is unclear whether you expect the `Customer_Det` field to hold one or several users…

Comment: I was expecint the Customer_Det to hold the details of 1 customer. so the Customer_Det field will hold the customer instance (basically his ID and his details correspoding to the user model) ,The campaign_det field will hold The Campaign details.